# When you perfect-forward, typename T becomes a T& or T&&, but when you don't, T isn't a reference at all. How?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm reading about perfect forwarding, and this is something I've learnt that has confused me: 
When you're trying to achieve perfect forwarding, you'll do something like this:

```
template<class T> // If I were to call foo with an l-value int, foo would look
void foo(T &&x);  // like this: void foo(int& &&x)
```

So then I thought, wait, does that mean that if I did this:

```
template<class T> // If I were to call foo with an l-value int, foo would look
void foo(T x);    // like this: void foo(int& x);
```

But that's not what happens. *foo* instead looks like this: `void foo(int x);`

**My question: How come in the perfect forwarding function, T turns into a T& or T&&, but in the other one, T isn't a reference? Can somebody tell me the exact rules for this? I need some clarification!**

Comment: When `T&&` can be become an l-value or r-value reference is what Scott Meyers refers to as "_Universal Reference_". (I feel that this terminology is getting more adoption among the experts.) I suggest you to take a look at [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) presentaion and read his article in [Overload 111](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload111.pdf).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A template parameter `T` can be deduced as a reference type **only** if it appears in a function parameter of the form `T&&`

A function template of the form:

- `template<class T> void f(T x)`

  will deduce `T` as an object type (and `x` is an object type so is passed by value)
- `template<class T> void f(T& x)`

  will deduce `T` as an object type (and then `x` has lvalue reference type)
- `template<class T> void f(T&& x)`

  will deduce `T` as

  - *either* an lvalue reference (so `x` has lvalue reference type due to reference collapsing rules)
  - *or* as an object type (so `x` has rvalue reference type)

> **How come in the perfect forwarding function, T turns into a T& or T&&, *[...]***

This is wrong.  `T` becomes a **reference type `L&`** or **an object type `R`**, *not* a reference `R&&`.
The function parameter of the form `T&&` thus becomes

- either `L&` (because adding an rvalue reference to an lvalue reference is still an lvalue reference, just like `add_rvalue_reference<L&>::type` is still `L&`)
- or it becomes `R&&` (because `add_rvalue_reference<R>::type` is `R&&`)

Comment: You gave (IMHO) the easiest to understand answer, so i'm accepting yours. Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 7):

This is because of the way *type deduction* is defined, and it is only related to perfect forwarding in the sense that the result of `std::forward<>()` is an rvalue if an rvalue reference is passed, and an lvalue if an lvalue reference is passed.

But in general, **when you do not have a reference to begin with, your `T` is not going to be deduced as a reference type** (i.e. as `A&`, whatever `A` could be). If that was the case, as [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192796/when-you-perfect-forward-typename-t-becomes-a-t-or-t-but-when-you-dont-t/16192955#comment23151213_16192955) correctly points out in the comments, it would be impossible to write a function template that takes its arguments by value.

In particular, the reference collapsing rule you are referring to is defined in Paragraph 14.8.2.1/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> If P is a
>   reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction. **If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified
>   template parameter and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in
>   place of A for type deduction**. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> template <class T> int f(T&&);
> template <class T> int g(const T&&);
> int i;
> int n1 = f(i); // calls f<int&>(int&)
> int n2 = f(0); // calls f<int>(int&&)
> int n3 = g(i); // error: would call g<int>(const int&&), which
> // would bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

Comment: Why might be useful as well.  If `template<typename T> void foo(T t)` could deduce `T=int&`, it would be impossible to deduce a template function that took arguments by value, because there is always a valid reference type (be it `T&&`, `T&`, `T const&` or `T const&&`) for any argument.  And on the other end, the ability for `T` in `T&&` to be deduced as a reference type makes perfect forwarding possible without writing 4 functions each time you want to do it.  It does make it tricky to write a function that takes any type as an rvalue reference, however.

Comment: @Yakk: That's true. I will mention this with a reference to your comment. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

There are three general cases to consider when deducing template parameters like this.

1. `void foo(T x)`: this means "pass-by-value". It always deduces a type as appropriate to pass by value.
2. `void foo(T& x)`: this means "pass-by-lvalue-reference". It always deduces a type as appropriate to pass by lvalue reference.
3. `void foo(T&& x)`: this means "pass-by-reference". It always deduces a type as appropriate to pass by reference, which may be an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 6):

Relax, slow down, and breathe.

*Template argument deduction* is the central mechanism that you need to understand, and it's not totally trivial. When you say `template <typename T> void foo(T)`, then `T` is *always* deduced as a non-reference type.

If you want a reference, you have to put a `&` on it: `template <typename T> void foo(T&)` will also deduce `T` as a non-reference-type, but `foo` now always expects an lvalue reference.

The final piece of magic comes from the new reference collapsing rules. When you say `template <typename T> void foo(T&&)`, then two things can happen:

- You call `foo` with an rvalue, e.g. `foo(Bar())`. Then `T` is deduced as `Bar`, and `foo` takes an rvalue reference to `Bar`, i.e. a `Bar&&`.
- You call `foo` with an lvalue, e.g. `Bar x; foo(x);`. Now the only thing `foo` can take is an lvalue reference. This requires `T` to be deduced as `Bar&`, since `T&& == Bar& && == Bar&`, due to the collapsing rules.

Only this final template is able to accept both lvalues and rvalues. This is why it is sometimes called "universal reference"; but remember that it's not the reference that matters, but the template argument deduction. Using `std::forward<T>` allows you to pass on the argument with the same value category that you received.