# Scott Meyers on Rvalueness

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I watched [Scott Meyers's extremely informative video on Universal References](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11), in which I learned most of what I know about Rvalue references, moving, and forwarding. At one point he was talking about *rvalueness* as opposed to the *type* of a variable, and he said something to the effect of "rvalueness is independent of type".

I understand that you can have a method like this:

```
void func(MyType&& rRef)
{
    // Do domething with rRef...
}
```

and that here `rRef` is an lvalue because it can be identified, its address can be taken, etc., even though its type is `MyType&&`.

But an rvalue cannot be *any* type, can it? I mean, it can only be a `MyType&&`, right? In that sense I thought type is not entirely independent of rvalueness. Maybe I'm missing something.

**Updated:** My point can be made clearer like this. If in `func()` I call one of two overloaded functions defined as

```
void gunc(MyType&& rRef)
{
   // ...
}

void gunc(MyType& lRef)
{
   // ...
}
```

i.e. either by calling `gunc(std::move(rRef))` or `gunc(rRef)`, it seems that the *type* of the resulting expression between parenthesis is not independent of rvalueness.

Comment: In expressions, references are removed from the type "prior to further analysis" [expr]/5. They're only used to distinguish the value category of some expressions (e.g. return values). Therefore, `rRef` as an id-expression is of type `MyType`. R/Lvalueness is a property of *expressions*, not of *types*.

Comment: Note: Let `string x; string& y = x; string&& z = move(x);`. Then `x`, `y` and `z` as id-expressions all are lvalues. It's more obvious that there should be no difference between `x` and `y`, even though `x` has been declared as `string`, whereas `y` has been declared as `string&`. Similarly, it would be problematic if `z` was an rvalue: It could allow moving twice from it implicitly, e.g. `string a0 = z; string a1 = z;`

Comment: Example without ampersands adding confusion: Given `int i; i; i + 0;`, The expression `i` is an lvalue of type `int`. `i+0` is an rvalue - technically prvalue - also of type `int`. They differ in value category despite having the same type.

Comment: So... can a string& *ever* be an rvalue? Maybe that's what my question boils down to.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato Any `T&` will be an lvalue.  `T&&` will always either be an rvalue or an universal reference (which can be an lvalue - if you initialized it with one).  Meyers at one point had a rule of thumb - if you can take the address of something, it is an lvalue.  Kerrek's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16192996/529761) explains it pretty well.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato I'm not sure if this question makes sense. As I said, rvalueness is a property of expressions, and there are no expressions of type `string&`.

Comment: Urgh... the headache! Who is right?

Comment: @KristianD'Amato [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16192961/529761) answer may also clear things up for you.  It hits on what your updated question is asking.

Comment: Btw, DyP, I was referring to the parentheses of the calling lines inside `func()`, not the parameter declarations of `gunc()`.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato It will call the appropriate function based on the level of indirection it is closest to.  That is, if you do not declare `func(T&)`, but do declare `func(T&&)`, you can call it in either of the following ways:  `func(T());` or `T t; func(t);`.  However, you cannot call `func(T&)` via `func(T())`.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato Ah! Ok. But nevertheless the type of both `std::move(rRef)` and `rRef` (as an expression) is just `int`. The r/lvalueness is used to select an overload (in this case: an lvalue cannot bind to `MyType&&` and an rvalue cannot bind to `MyType&`, so there's only one viable overload for each case).

Comment: @DyP thanks. I guess that explains it. My brain couldn't handle the fact that overloading here was on r/lvalueness, not on type.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato Consider `void gunc(MyType);` vs. `void gunc(MyType&);` The call `MyType x; gunc(x);` shouldn't chose another function than `MyType& y = x; gunc(x);`, so it's just dismissed as ambiguous.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I was seeing the declared type only, which obviously doesn't make sense as you well showed. Still a lot to learn!

Comment: Terminology: the "lvalueness" or "rvalueness" of an expression is its *value category*. As you say, it's separate from the *type*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *type* of an expression does not have any traces of references. So if *for a moment we assume that references could have reference type*, then we would have the following

```
int a = 0;
int &ra = a;

int c = a + 42;
int d = ra + 42;
```

In the above, the expression `a` *would* have type `int`, and the expression `ra` *would* have type `int&`. I think that in nearly all the rules of the spec that relate expressions to type, for example rules that say "expression E must be of type X", we would have to add "... or reference to type X" (think about cast operators). So my educated guess is that this would be too much of a burden to be useful.

---

C++ has the following types

- static type of an expression

Just called "type of the expression" (if not otherwise specified that the dynamic one is meant). This is a property of expressions that designate the type of expressions *abstracted away of what the expression refers to* at compile time. For example if `a` refers to an `int&` or `int` variable, or is a literal `0`, all those expression have type `int`.

- dynamic type of an lvalue expression

This is the type that the non-base-class object that an lvalue expression refers to has.

```
ofstream fs("/log");
ostream &os = fs;
```

In this, `os` has the *static type* `ostream` and the *dynamic type* `ofstream`.

- type of an object or reference

This is the type that an object or reference actually has. An object always has a single type and its type never changes. But what object exists at what location is something only known at runtime, so generally, "type of an object" is a runtime thing too

```
ostream *os;
if(file)
  os = new ofstream("/log");
else
  os = new ostringstream;
```

The type of the object denoted by `*os` (and the dynamic type of the lvalue `*os` aswell) is  known only at runtime

```
int *p = new int[rand() % 5 + 1];
```

Here, the type of the array that was created by operator new is only known at runtime too, and (thanksfully) does and can not escape to the static C++ type system. The infamous aliasing rule (that forbids reading objects from incompatible lvalues, roughly speaking) speaks of "dynamic type" of objects, presumably because it wants to highlight that runtime concerns are of interests. But strictly speaking, saying "dynamic type" of an object is weird, because an object doesn't have a "static type".

- declared type of a variable or member

This is the type that you gave in a declaration. In relation to the type of an object or the type of an expression, this sometimes can be subtly different

```
struct A {
  A() { }
  int a;
};

const A *a = new const A;
volatile const A *va = a;
```

Here, the expression `a->a` has type `const int`, but the declared type of the member that `a->a` resolves to has type `int` (the member entity). The type of the object denoted by `a->a` has type `const int`, because we created a `const A` object with the `new` expression, and therefore all non-static data members are implicitly `const` subobjects. In `va->a`, the expression has type `volatile const int a`, and the declared type of the variable still has type `int` and the type of the object referred to still has type `const int`.

---

When you say "type of a" and you declared "a" as "int &a;" you therefor always have to say what you mean by "type of a". Do you mean the expression? Then "a" has type `int`. It can even become nastier. Imagine "int a[10];". Here the expression "a" has type `int*` or `int[10]` depending on whether you consider the array to pointer conversion to have taken place in your expression or not, when you ask for the "type of a". If you ask for the type of the variable referred to by "a", then the answer uniquely is `int` and `int[10]` respectively.

---

So what type can an rvalue be of? Rvalues are expressions.

```
int &&x = 0;
int y = std::move(x);
int z = x;
```

Here, we have rvalues `0`, and `std::move(x)`. Both rvalues have type `int`. The expression `x` appearing in the initializer for `z` is an lvalue, even though it refers to the same object that the rvalue `std::move(x)` refers to.

---

Your last point in your question about the overloaded function called with an rvalue or lvalue respectively is interesting. Just because rvalue references are written as `int &&` does not mean that rvalues have type `int`. They are called rvalue references because you can initialize them with rvalues and the language prefers that initialization over initializing an lvalue reference with an rvalue.

---

Also, it may be useful to see expressions in name-form that are rvalues

```
enum A { X };
template<int Y> struct B { };
```

If you use `X` or `Y`, they are rvalues. But those cases are the only one that I can think of.

Comment: Thanks Johannes. That's a very detailed response, and explains my confusion. I will give some time and pick it as the right answer!

Comment: Two questions, if you don't mind: 1. When can the dynamic type of an expression and the type of an object/reference (presumably referred to by the first expression) come apart, if at all? 2. You write `Just because rvalue references are written as int && does not mean that rvalues have type int`. Can you expound on this, please?

Comment: *When can the dynamic type of an expression and the type of an object/reference (presumably referred to by the first expression) come apart, if at all?* (note that I edited my answer. initially I forgot to mention the important point, that the most derived class is what the dynamic type of an lvalue is about). To answer: Not sure whether you meant this, but this can happen if you have classes and base classes. So `ofstream of("/log"); ostream &os = of;` Here, `os` refers to the base-class subobject of type `ostream` within the complete `ofstream` object that `of` refers to.

Comment: I don't know the precise meaning of "refers" and "denotes". When defining the meaning of "dynamic type" of an lvalue, the spec uses "refers": "type of the most derived object (1.8) to which the glvalue denoted by a glvalue expression refers". Stricly speaking, I don't think "os" above does really "refer" to the most derived object, but just to one of its base class subobjects. I hope you know what I want to say, though :) In some sense it "touches" the most derived object :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are leaving off part of his quote:

> A final point is worth bearing in mind: the lvalueness or rvalueness
>   of an expression is independent of its type.

He explains it [here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).  His main point was this:

> The type of an expression does not tell you whether it is an lvalue or
>   an rvalue.

And in his concluding remarks:

> In a type declaration, “&&” indicates either an rvalue reference or a
>   universal reference – a reference that may resolve to either an lvalue
>   reference or an rvalue reference. Universal references always have the
>   form T&& for some deduced type T.
>
> Reference collapsing is the mechanism that leads to universal
>   references (which are really just rvalue references in situations
>   where reference-collapsing takes place) sometimes resolving to lvalue
>   references and sometimes to rvalue references. It occurs in specified
>   contexts where references to references may arise during compilation.
>   Those contexts are template type deduction, auto type deduction,
>   typedef formation and use, and decltype expressions.

The type `T` is used here to mean *any* type.  It could be `int&&`, or `double&&`, or `Widget&&` - it doesn't matter.

Comment: Or "any value with a *name* is *always* an lvalue in an expression (after its initial construction)".  It may be an rvalue reference, but that *only* determines what it is allowed to bind to.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not sure I follow the second part of your comment.  Can you expound?

Comment: `foo get_foo();  foo&& tmp = get_foo();` is legal, while `foo& tmp = get_foo();` is not, as a variable of type `foo&` cannot bind to a temporary, while a variable of type `foo&&` can.  See http://ideone.com/zrP9oY for an example.  That, and `decltype`, are (almost?) the only differences between `foo&&` and `foo&` variable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's limit the discussion to plain rvalue references and leave universal references aside. We're not talking about `template <typename T> ... T &&var ...`

As far as regular `Type &&var = somevalue;` case of rvalue reference, I think the meaning of it is this:

Whatever is bound to this reference was "disposable" when it was bound to the reference. It was going out of scope. If you modified it at the moment you bound it, no one would ever know. There were no other references to it at the time it was bound.

This allows us to take some liberties with rvalue references that we cannot take with other kinds of variables. The first use that comes to mind is to steal its contents with swap().

Comment: *"This allows us to take some liberties with rvalue references that we cannot take with other kinds of variables. The first use that comes to mind is to steal its contents with swap()."* `var`, although being declared as a variable of rvalue reference type, is an lvalue (as an id-expression). From an example I posted as a comment to the OP: `string&& rv = string(); string x = rv; string y = rv;` You cannot safely move from an rvalue-reference variable, as it can be referred to after the move.

Comment: Very true. That's why I keep saying "when it was bound". You have to be careful to not create more references to rvalue between binding and going out of scope. On the other hand, I think your example as posted in your comment to my answer is fairly safe. It would be unsafe if `x` or `y` were references.

Comment: Oops, sorry - I forgot that copy constructor does not have to make actual copy. So yes, your example is unsafe in general sense, although it should be safe for strings.

Comment: What I meant is: *If* `rv` *were* an rvalue, then `string x = rv;` would call the *move*-constructor. Then, `x == y` wouldn't hold in the general case. But luckily, `rv` is an lvalue, therefore `string x = rv;` calls the copy-ctor (which is assumed not to change `rv`).

Comment: In `string x = rv` rv cannot be an rvalue: it's a named variable and therefore an lvalue.

Comment: I've been making a hypothetical statement under the counterfactual assumption that `rv` would be an rvalue. Of course *it is not an rvalue in the current Standard*. I wanted to point out that you shouldn't treat variables of rvalue reference type differently from variables of non-reference type.